# How to extract last 2 characters before the extension of a filename in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, ksh

What i would like to accomplish is to take a file name let's say `myfileRE.txt` and return the new file name of `myfile.txt`. The extra two characters will always be two characters and so what i tried to do was:

```
${filename%??.}
```

and my idea was "match the 2 characters that come right before the period and rip those characters out" ..unfortunately that just returned the entire filename.

I ended up doing this:

```
${filename%??????}.txt
```

but that's not very friendly and there must be a cleaner way to do it. Any advice? Maybe something with regular expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to pull something out of the middle of a string, you can use a substitution. The following works in bash:

```
filename=myfileRE.txt
echo "${filename/??./.}"
```

This is matching the pattern "??." and replacing it with ".". It is similar to a `perl` or `sed` substitution, except it uses shell pattern matching instead of regex.

Comment: This is perfect but what exactly is it doing? It doesn't look like a string operator to me.

Comment: okay cool i thought it looked very similar to `sed`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Jordanm's approach is probably the way to go, but just for variety

```
echo "${filename%%??.*}.${filename#*.}"
```

Comment: Your approach does have benefit of being POSIX, where mine is not.

Comment: jordanm's method is better. It's not going to work well with filenames like `myfileRE.tar.gz`.

Comment: @konsolebox, the latest version handles the `myfileRE.tar.gz` case, but yes, jordan's solution is better